# multi row table

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to replicate the hand drawn table in latex.

[image: desired output]

So far what I have is the following code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}{
\setlength\arraycolsep{6pt} % default is "5pt"
$\begin{array}{lccc}
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{SECTION A} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Number of}\\\text{questions}\end{array}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Number of questions}\\\text{to be answered}\end{array}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Number of}\\\text{marks}\end{array}}\\[0.224cm]
\hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{36} \\[0.224cm]
\hline
\text{SECTION B} & \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Number of}\\\text{questions}\end{array} & \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Number of questions}\\\text{to be answered}\end{array} & \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Number of}\\\text{marks}\end{array}\\[0.124cm]
\hline
& 4 & 2 & 24\\ 
\hline
&  &  & \text{Total }60\\
\hline
\end{array}$}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It seems to generate somewhat a similar table (as shown below), however the multi-row in the first column for Section A and Section B is not happening.

[image: What I am getting]

How do I achieve this? I also what to horizontally and vertically centre the texts in the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{SECTION A}
    & \makecell{Number of\\ questions}
        & \makecell{Number of questions\\ to be answered}
            & \makecell{Number of\\ marks}      \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & 7 & 7 & 36                                \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{SECTION B}
    & \makecell{Number of\\ questions}
        & \makecell{Number of questions\\ to be answered}
            & \makecell{Number of\\ marks}      \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & 4 & 2 & 24                                \\
    \midrule
    &   &   & Total 60                          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

is this what you looking for?

as you can see, in above mwe (minimal working example) i remove from your code all what is not related to table. also i remove all not needed code complications as use `\multicolumn` for one column cells. observe, that instead `hline` are used rules from `booktabls`: `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`. for two line cells' content is used `\makecell` from the `\makecell` package.

Answer (score 3):

<s>An alternative using the very powerful and versatile `tabu` package:</s>
Apparently the `tabu` package is considered obsolete (thanks @Zarko for the heads-up), but the same effect can be achieved with the `tabulary` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabulary}{0.8\linewidth}{l*{3}{C}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{SECTION A} & Number of questions & Number of questions to be answered & Number of marks \\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        & 7 & 7 & 36 \\\midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{SECTION B} & Number of questions & Number of questions to be answered & Number of marks \\\cmidrule{2-4}
        & 4 & 2 & 24 \\\midrule
        & & & Total 60\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

But I believe you don't really need multirows, if you use the table like this:

[image]

With

```
    \begin{tabulary}{0.8\linewidth}{l*{3}{C}}
        \toprule
        & Number of questions & Number of questions to be answered & Number of marks \\
        \midrule
        Section A & 7 & 7 & 36 \\
        Section B & 4 & 2 & 24 \\
        \midrule
        Total & & & 60\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
```

Comment: your second table is nice, however, i would not use `tabu`. it is not maintained and buggy.

Comment: @Zarko I was unaware of that, I've been using it for quite some time and have never encountered bugs I believe. Maybe I haven't stretched its abilities with my use-cases :) I will adjust my answer. What package would you recommend as alternative?

Comment: mostly it works. but now, after new version of the `array` package, it become incompatible to it (when you use `m` columns) and you will have problems  with before normally working tables.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, with a simpler code, based on `makecell`. I don't think you need an `array` environment for this table, `tabular` is just fine here, and using systematically  the rules form `booktabs` will save you typing additional  spacings like`[0.224mm]` since these rules incorporate some vertical padding.

Also, don't load a package several times. Note that `xcolor` already loads `color`, `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, `blkarray` loads `array`. Last, not least, `hyperref`  should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{blkarray, multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
\multirowcell{3.3}{SECTION A} & \makecell{Number of \\ questions} & \makecell{Number of questions \\ to be answered} & \makecell{Number of \\ marks}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{36} \\
\midrule
 \multirowcell{3.4}{SECTION B} & \makecell{Number of \\ questions} & \makecell{Number of questions \\ to be answered} & \makecell{Number of \\ marks}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
& 4 & 2 & 24\\
\midrule
& & & \text{Total }60\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With overleaf.com, there are .3 and .4 printed above Section A and Section B, it looks like misunderstanding \multirowcell{3.3}. How to fix these errors?

Comment: @pzorba75: Does overleaf use a (comparatively) recent version of multirow. Last version is 2.2, dating back to 25/11/2016. A work-around would consist in using the optional argument  of `\multirow` something like `\multirowcell[3}[-2pt]{SECTION A}` yields the same result as `\multirowcell{3.3}{SECTION A}`, as far as I ca see.